# iPhone - Send contents of webview as mail

Tags: iphone, email, uiwebview

I'm composing my messages using images, text and audio files and finally showing the preview in Webview. Now, I want to send what ever it is showing in web view as mail. Even images and audio files must be sent so that end user has just to see the message with all images and aduio files as in original message.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Send the actual HTML of the web page. Be sure to set the  in the page, so any links in the page will be referenced relative to the original URL. There are upsides and downsides to this method:

UPSIDE: Small file will be sent - just the HTML of the base page

DOWNSIDE: Any images and sounds will not be sent in the message - and will have to be downloaded by the users email client from the original URL when the page is viewed. (Any web client that supports HTML content type will be able to do this.)

Don't forget to set the content (MIME) type of the email message to TEXT/HTML.